# SFMC - How do you query a LIST?

Tags: list, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I want to query a LIST inside Marketing cloud, and then use Automation Studio to send subscribers from that list to a Data Extension.

But I don't see a method of querying a custom list?

The list is stored under "Subscribers > MyList".

[MYList Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FOSR.png)

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [query](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query) tags.

Answer (score 0):

The [_ListSubscribers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=5) data view contains subscribers associated with all lists.  You'll need to narrow it down by ListID.

You'll find the ID of the List in its properties.

All lists share Profile Attribute values, which can be found in the [_EnterpriseAttribute](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_enterpriseattribute.htm&type=5) data view.  You can relate that back to _ListSubscribers using the SubscriberID.

Comment: Thank you, I did try to query _ListSubscribers using ListID, but they are not in _ListSubscribers yet.  Is this due to not sending an email out to the list?  The list is populated via a form that is connected to marketing cloud through an API.